# Using python, how to change Dimensions and aspect ratio of SVG file

Tags: python, svg, cairo

Iam trying to change the dimensions of SVG file in python  using the following code

```
from cairosvg import svg2svg
input_path="/home/user/Desktop/in.svg"
output_path="/home/user/Desktop/out.svg"
svg2svg(url=input_path,output_width=1600,output_height=1000, write_to=output_path)
```

However, the aspect ratio is being kept according to input file.

How do i resize an SVG in python according to new dimensions(newWidth x newHeight) and their corresponding aspect ratio(newWidth/newHeight).

Answer (score 0):

For those interested in the solution, we can modify content of svg file(which essentially is an xml file) using python.

We need to add the  preserveAspectRatio='none' to the svg tag in order to ignore original aspect ratio and resize according to explicitly defined dimensions.

code as follows:

```
import cairosvg

filename='/home/user/Desktop/output1.svg' #original file
output_file"/home/user/Desktop/Test3.svg"

Change = open(filename, "r")
data = Change.read()
data = data.replace('<svg ', '<svg preserveAspectRatio="none" ')
Change.close()
Change = open(filename, "w+")
Change.write(data)
Change.close()

cairosvg.svg2svg(url=filename, write_to=output_file, output_width=2000,output_height=1000)
```